# Using images in CSS with Jinja and Django

Tags: python, css, django, jinja2

I am making my first blog with Django, everything is working fine, but I can seem to load my burger img with CSS in my *blog_app*.

```
 blog_app
-templates
--include_core
---blog.html
--blog_app
---blog_app.html
---blog_post.html
-static
--include_core
---fonts
---js
---css
----mobile.css
----style.css
---images
----mobile
-----mobile-menu.png
```

so include_core is basicly the folder where the main template will be placed. It is working perfectly.

I tried with this example and everything was working fine:

```
<img src="{% static 'include_core/images/moon-satellite.jpg' %}" alt="">
```

blog_app/templates/include_core/blog.html

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><!-- blog - Space Science Website Template --></title>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'include_core/css/style.css' %}" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'include_core/css/mobile.css' %}">
    <script src="{% static 'include_core/js/mobile.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

blog_app/static/include_core/mobile.css

```
#header div span#mobile-navigation {
    background: transparent url("images/mobile/mobile-menu.png") no-repeat;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 3%;
    top: 14px;
    width: 50px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

JavaScript file:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var getNavi = document.getElementById('navigation');

    var mobile = document.createElement("span");
    mobile.setAttribute("id","mobile-navigation");
    getNavi.parentNode.insertBefore(mobile,getNavi);

    document.getElementById('mobile-navigation').onclick = function(){
        var a = getNavi.getAttribute('style');
        if(a){
            getNavi.removeAttribute('style');
            document.getElementById('mobile-navigation').style.backgroundImage='url(images/mobile/mobile-menu.png)';
        } else {
            getNavi.style.display='block';
            document.getElementById('mobile-navigation').style.backgroundImage='url(images/mobile/mobile-close.png)';
        }
    };
```

Here is the problem: in the desktop version there shouldn't be no hamburger button(mobile-menu.png), there should be only in the mobile version. When I reduce my browser width, all the paragraph, elements get ordered the way they should have been ordered but that images never comes up, can you what should I do to make it appear ?